# Can't get HP printer to work with ubuntu

Tags: printing, hp

On Edit:

Trying to use an HP Envy 5660 multifunction printer/scanner in 20.04 LTS.  On installing Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows 10), the printer at least worked.  It named the printer Envy5600_asdfhasfhad_gobbledegook. Or somesuch.  I couldn't scan, and wanted to, so tried installing HPLIP 3.20.3. It recognizes the printer, then throws a communication error.  And I end up with three printers (one called Envy5660, and the other two with a lot of letters and numbers appended to the name.  So the Ubuntu Printers window shows three instances of the printer.  I can print from two of them.  One (the one with the plain name) accepts jobs into queue and then just sits there.    If I open HPLIP, it shows the printer, but does not show a scanner (the printer is a combo unit).  And initially it showed a com error.

Document scan finds scanners, and one appears to work (I have to remember which one).  I'd really like to be be able to use HP scanner/printer control software, but HPLIP fails.

I've been informed that Linux printer support is exceptionally weak (multiple sources, all Linux users), and this seems to confirm that impression.  Are printer issues like this just accepted?  That seems to make Linux/Ubuntu rather a second-tier, specialist's O/S.

It's a bit of a drag to have to reboot to Windows 10 to use my scanner.  Any ideas on how to make the scanner work?

Comment: Please [edit] you question to indicate which version of HPLIP you have installed. Is it the printer that is not working or just scanning? Did you check the HPLIP database to check which version will work with your printer? There are references on ask ubuntu in regard to preventing the automatic addition of printers - did you investigate this too?

Comment: The latest HPLIP: 3.20.3. The printer(s) installed using HPLIP don't work, and throw a Device Communications Error (5102).  The printer appears to print ok using the non-HPLIP connection, but won't scan.  And the printer will neither print nor scan when using the printers installed using HPLIP.